# DataTable as return data type for a method in Web Service asmx for SharePoint

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint

I create a web service fro SharePoint to return two values, but I could not use a DataTable as a return type for the method.

How can I make this method to return two difference values(difference data types) in a `List<>`?

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true, Description=" Get All sites in the Site Collection.")]
public List<string> GetAllSites(string InputSitecollectionUrl)
{
    List<string> w = new List<string>();
    using (SPSite TargetsiteCollection = new SPSite(InputSitecollectionUrl))
    {
        SPWebCollection allWebs = TargetsiteCollection.AllWebs;
        foreach (SPWeb web in allWebs)
        {
            string WebUrl = web.Url;
            string WebTitle = web.Title;

            w.Add(WebUrl);
            w.Add(WebTitle);
        }
    }
    return w;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than returning a `List<string>` you'll probably want to use a `List<KeyValuePair<T1, T2>>`

```
var w = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
foreach (SPWeb web in allWebs)
{
    w.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(web.Url, web.Title));
}

return w;
```

You can specify whatever type suits your needs in the KeyValuePair type constraints.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, actually I found another technique , I used a DataSet this give me chance to named the returned DataTable columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataSet set = new DataSet("sites");
        DataTable table1 = new DataTable("site");
        table1.Columns.Add("SiteUrl");
        table1.Columns.Add("SiteTitle");

        // Create a DataSet and put both tables in it.
        using (SPSite TargetsiteCollection = new SPSite(InputSitecollectionUrl))
        {
            SPWebCollection allWebs = TargetsiteCollection.AllWebs;
            foreach (SPWeb web in allWebs)
            {
                string WebUrl = web.Url;
                string WebTitle = web.Title;
                table1.Rows.Add(WebUrl, WebTitle);
            }
            set.Tables.Add(table1);

        }
        return set;
```